Disable Universal Clipboard popups
Is there a way to stop the popups from Universal Clipboard, but leave clipboard sharing on?

You mean the "copying from Fred's MacBook" alert that briefly shows up? No.

Do you mean "pasting from Fred's MacBook"?  I only see popups like that when the copied text/links, etc. is slightly more complicated.  If it's straight forward normal short text, nothing pops up here.  But I'm also using a clipboard manager on the Mac, which could influence the feature.
